# Button value not sent in formdata to servlet

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am using multiple buttons and only one of them can be selected (like a group of radio buttons). I am trying to get the value of the button which is selected in my servlet, but it is returning null. I have attached my code below.

**JS PAGE**

```
$.each($('.radio-btn'), function(key, value) {
  $(this).click(function(e) {
    $('.radio-btn-selected').removeClass('radio-btn-selected').addClass('radio-btn');
    $(this).removeClass('radio-btn').addClass('radio-btn-selected');

    // do whatever you want on click
  });
});
```

**CSS PAGE**

```
.radio-btn {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #4A4A4A;
  color: #4A5362;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 26px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-btn-selected {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #55BC7E;
  color: #55BC7E;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 26px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 7px;
  cursor: no-drop;
}
```

**JSP PAGE**

```
<form action="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/BookAppointment" method="POST">
  <div class="timmings">
    <div id="ajaxResponse" style="display:none">
      <div class="radio-btn-row">
        <div class="radio-btn-wrapper">
          <button id="bt1" class="radio-btn" name="slot" type="button" value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</button>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-btn-wrapper">
          <button id="btn2" class="radio-btn" name="slot" type="button" value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</button>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-btn-wrapper">
          <button id="btn3" class="radio-btn" name="slot" type="button" value="3:00 PM">03:00 PM</button>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-btn-wrapper">
          <button id="btn4" class="radio-btn" name="slot" type="button" value="3:30 PM">03:30 PM</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="book" style="display:none"><input type="submit" class="submit" value="Book Appointment"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Servlet Page**

```
package com.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/BookAppointment")
public class BookAppointment extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public BookAppointment() {

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String date=request.getParameter("date");
        String slot=request.getParameter("slot");
        System.out.println(date+" "+slot1);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code which returns a `null` value?. You just need to use `this.value` to get the value of the clicked button.

Comment: Its in my servlet. Wait Let me attach the code of the servlet also

Comment: So you're expecting the value of the button which was clicked to be sent in the form data? That's not how buttons work. If you want that behaviour you will need to manually set the value of the clicked button in to a hidden field. Or alternatively, I would suggest you amend the HTML to use radio buttons which you style with CSS to keep the current UI.

Comment: No No No, I have a form in which there are multiple buttons, and if any one of them is clicked. I want the value of that button... I tried using a single name for all the buttons and also by using different names for all the buttons. But both are returning null

Comment: Please be clear. ***WHERE*** do you want to read the button value? In the client-side JS or the server side Java servlet?

Comment: JAVA SERVLET....

Comment: Then my previous comment is correct, you're not using buttons correctly and will need follow the advice I made there.

Comment: Okay, so how can I do that. can you please explain to me with some code or a fiddle or something

Comment: Sure, I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be expecting the value of the 'selected' button to be sent in the form submission - this is not how buttons work. To fix this you will need to amend either your JS or HTML.

The first approach would be to include a hidden field which you update when a button is selected. Note in your jQuery that you don't need the `$.each()` loop; `click()` will be applied to all elements in the jQuery object.

```js
$('.radio-btn').click(function(e) {
  $('.radio-btn-selected').removeClass('radio-btn-selected').addClass('radio-btn');
  $(this).removeClass('radio-btn').addClass('radio-btn-selected');

  $('#slot').val(this.value);
});
```

```css
.radio-btn-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.radio-btn-wrapper {
  margin: 0px 4px;
}

.radio-btn {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #4A4A4A;
  color: #4A5362;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 26px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-btn-selected {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #55BC7E;
  color: #55BC7E;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 26px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 7px;
  cursor: no-drop;
}

.radio-btn-disabled {
  cursor: no-drop;
}

.submit {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #33b5e5;
  border: 2px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/BookAppointment" method="POST">
  <div class="timmings">
    <div id="ajaxResponse">
      <!-- style="display:none"> -->
      <div class="radio-btn-row">
        <div class="radio-btn-wrapper">
          <button id="bt1" class="radio-btn" name="slot-button" type="button" value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</button>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-btn-wrapper">
          <button id="btn2" class="radio-btn" name="slot-button" type="button" value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</button>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-btn-wrapper">
          <button id="btn3" class="radio-btn" name="slot-button" type="button" value="3:00 PM">03:00 PM</button>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-btn-wrapper">
          <button id="btn4" class="radio-btn" name="slot-button" type="button" value="3:30 PM">03:30 PM</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="book" style="display:none"><input type="submit" class="submit" value="Book Appointment"></div>
  </div>

  <input type="text" id="slot" name="slot" />
  <!-- make this hidden in your production version -->
</form>
```

The alternative approach would be to amend your HTML so that instead of using button elements, which don't send a value in the request, change them to actual `radio` inputs which do. In addition it means you don't need the JS to add/remove classes as the styling can all be done through CSS.

Comment: Good approach, Thanks. I am gonna try it in my code and then I will let you know :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help